# I need to get running total for everday enrollment

Tags: sql, powerbi

Hi Need to calculate running total for everyday enrollment. Please find below screenshot.

[In the below image total seven user enrolled on particular day. means running count is 7. Like this i need for everyday] in Power Bi or SQL anything is fine.
Need help on this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3U1i.png)

Comment: Analytic /window functions `select count(*) over (partition by [Date column]) FROM tableName`

Comment: this is working as expected but i need to add more to this.  i need to add running total to next date running total and it need goes still end.

Comment: Please provide sample data: expected results.  your image only shows one element which Doesn't support your new statement. a running total would just be a count(*) over (Partition by Null) I believe.

Comment: Also; please state a complete question when asking and don't change the nature of the question once you have an answer.   it negates the purpose of a Q&A site like this.